# VBA to Lotus Notes - How to Add Attachment

Tags: vba, email, lotus-notes, attachment

i'm currently using the code below with some modifications to create my message but it's been a struggle to add to it attachment capabilities, can someone please help me with this one?

```
Sub Notes_Email_Excel_Cells()
Dim NSession As Object
Dim NDatabase As Object
Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
Dim NDoc As Object
Dim NUIdoc As Object

Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")

If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then
    NDatabase.OPENMAIL
End If

'Create a new document

Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument

With NDoc
    .SendTo = "email.address@email.com"
    .CopyTo = ""
    .subject = "Pasted Excel cells " & Now

    'Email body text, including marker text which will be replaced by the Excel cells

    .body = "Text in email body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "**PASTE EXCEL CELLS HERE**" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Excel cells are shown above"

    .Save True, False
End With

'Edit the just-created document to copy and paste the Excel cells into it

Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EDITDocument(True, NDoc)

With NUIdoc

    'Find the marker text in the Body item

    .GotoField ("Body")
    .FINDSTRING "data"

    'Replace it with the Excel cells

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E6").Copy
    .Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '.Send
    '.Close
End With

Set NSession = Nothing
End Sub
```

I do believe that i might have some success adding the following lines, but i still have to test it at work, as i'm posting from my PC:

```
Dim notesRichTextItem As NotesRichTextItem
'[...]
Set notesRichTextItem = doc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
'[...]
Call notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", "File path")
```

I haven't really understood the EmbedObject parameters, as from what i've found on IBM Knowledge center didn't clear all of my doubts ( [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EMBEDOBJECT_METHOD.html) ), as you can find below

> **Defined in**
>
> NotesRichTextItem
>
> **Syntax**
>
> Set notesEmbeddedObject = notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject( type%, class$, source$, [ name$ ] )

Therefore it should be something like

```
notesEmbeddedObject = notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject(1454,"",**FILEPATH**,"")
```

Instead of my previous

```
    Call notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", "File path")
```

***but how will i add it to the end of the message? or even, how will i call it in the code?*** :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your initialization of `Body` field to `NotesRichTextItem` initialization.
Instead of:

```
.body = "Text in email body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "**PASTE EXCEL CELLS HERE**" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Excel cells are shown above"
```

Write this:

```
Set notesRichTextItem = .CreateRichTextItem("Body")
notesRichTextItem.AppendText("Text in email body")
notesRichTextItem.AddNewline(2)
notesRichTextItem.AppendText("**PASTE EXCEL CELLS HERE**")
notesRichTextItem.AddNewline(2)
notesRichTextItem.AppendText("Excel cells are shown above")
notesRichTextItem.AddNewline(1)
'And here comes the attachment:
Call notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", "File path")
```

Comment: Please note: since you are using the paste method to get the Excel data into the rich text, you will be dealing with the back end (NDoc) and front end (NUIDoc) objects. You're going to have to break up the above code into two pieces. The first part occurs before you do your work with the NUIdoc - and be sure to call NUIdoc.save(), and then the second part occurs after that.